# Are there any plans to make GTK3 apps look more native in KDE?

Tags: kubuntu, gtk3

This is stopping me from upgrading to the latest version of Kubuntu, and I realise that there are solutions out there but I would rather not have to resort to a third-party solution.

Comment: What third-party solution do you refer to?

Answer (score 1):

**oxygen-gtk3 ??**

If you mean the oxygen-gtk3

A wish (needs-packaging): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/825858

It has a link to the "HOWTO: gtk3-engines-oxygen for gtk3 apps": http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3118994.0

Peeking to the kubuntu-devel irc: http://irclogs.ubuntu.com/2011/12/21/%23kubuntu-devel.html

```
_Groo_  Riddell: btw it would be nice to add gtk3-engines-oxygen to the builds  17:55
_Groo_  Riddell: my desktop is much more pretty that way :D 17:55
Riddell yes I think that's on the precise todo  17:55
```

Maybe with the Kubuntu 12.04...

More of the 12.04: https://askubuntu.com/questions/81902/when-will-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin-be-released