# Gnome 3 application theme in kDE

Tags: gnome, kde, themes, kde4

I am using KDE 4 and when I run any Gnome 3 application it looks really bad, how I can make Gnome 3 applications have themes like in Unity and Gnome 3 Shell. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the oxygen-gtk3.

Earlier: [Are there any plans to make GTK3 apps look more native in KDE?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89469/are-there-any-plans-to-make-gtk3-apps-look-more-native-in-kde)

"HOWTO: gtk3-engines-oxygen for gtk3 apps": http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3118994.0